# Add a class if certain text is present

Tags: jquery

I am new to this site and new to jQuery so I applogise if I am doing this wrong.

I am working on a system that I do not have full code access, so I am having to use jQuery to influence some visual.

I wish to change the colour of a button (by adding an additional class) if certain text is present. This is what I have done so far:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if ($('#VALID_VAR_264 > div.validationError:contains("Required")').length > 0) {   
        $("#ccbutton").addClass("thisClass");
    }
</script>
```

So basically the validation will always have the word 'Required' if it is triggered. Here is the related page code. As I said, I dont have control over this so kind of have to work with what I have got.

```
<a onclick="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('div2');">
  <div id="ccbutton" class="ccbutton">View text options</div>
</a>
<div id="div2" class="cccontent">
  <div id=DIV_10828 class='Form_Header'>
    <p class='Form_Header'>Headers & body text </p>
      <script language="javascript">
        FieldIDs["HeaderHeader"] = 10828;
      </script>
    <div class='validationError' style='display:none' id='VALID_VAR_10828'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id=DIV_168 class=''>
    <p class=''>Enter a header</p>
    <p>
      <textarea rows=2 id='FIELD_168' name='FIELD_168' style='width: 200px; '>The activity, event or service header can go here. </textarea>
    </p>
    <script language="javascript">
      FieldIDs["Header"] = 168;
    </script>
    <div class='validationError' style='display:none' id='VALID_VAR_168'>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id=DIV_264 class='Form_Normal'>
    <p class='Form_Normal'>Enter a subheader</p>
    <p>
      <textarea rows=2 id='FIELD_264' name='FIELD_264'  style='width: 200px; '></textarea>
    </p>
    <script language="javascript">
      FieldIDs["Description"] = 264;
    </script>
    <div class='validationError' id='VALID_VAR_264'>Required</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `#VALID_VAR_264 > div.validationError` means that `class=validationError` should be in a child of `id=VALID_VAR_264`. But these are the same element in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments to your question, the ID and the class you are trying to reference are the same element.  I have made a snippet modifying your selector accordingly.

```js
if ($('#VALID_VAR_264.validationError:contains("Required")').length > 0) {   
$("#ccbutton").addClass("thisClass");
}
```

```css
#ccbutton{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.thisClass{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('div2');"><div id="ccbutton" class="ccbutton">View text options</div></a><div id="div2" class="cccontent"><div id=DIV_10828 class='Form_Header'><p class='Form_Header'>Headers & body text </p>
<div class='validationError' style='display:none' id='VALID_VAR_10828'></div>
</div>
<div id=DIV_168 class=''><p class=''>Enter a header</p><p><textarea rows=2 id='FIELD_168' name='FIELD_168' style='width: 200px; '>The activity, event or service header can go here. </textarea></p>
<div class='validationError' style='display:none' id='VALID_VAR_168'>    
</div>
</div>
<div id=DIV_264 class='Form_Normal'><p class='Form_Normal'>Enter a subheader</p><p><textarea rows=2 id='FIELD_264' name='FIELD_264'  style='width: 200px; '></textarea></p>
<div class='validationError' id='VALID_VAR_264'>Required</div>
</div>
```